# docker-compose 'ports' mapping in development vs travisCI

Tags: docker-compose, port, travis-ci

I have a development environment using docker-compose, it has 5 services:

- db (postrgresql)
- redis
- celery
- celery-beat
- web (a django web app - development is occurring here)

In development, I run the top four in containers with

`docker-compose up db redis celery celery-beat`

These four containers can connect to each other no problem.

However, while I code with the web app, I need to run it locally so I can get live updates and debug.  However, running locally, the web app can't connect with the containers, and I need to map the ports on the containers, e.g:

```
db: 
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

so that my locally running web app can connect with them.

However, if I then push my code to github, TravisCI fails it with this error:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hackerspace_db_1 (493e7fb9e53f551b3b1eea35f9e2baf5725e9077fc642d8121891cab31b34373): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
The command "docker-compose run web sh -c "python src/manage.py test src/"" exited with 1.
```

TravisCI passes without the port mapping, but I have to develop with port mapping.

How can I get around this so that they both work with the same settings?  I'm willing to try different workflows, as I'm new to docker and containers and trying to find my way around.

I've tried:

- Developing in a container with Visual Studio Code's `Remote - Containers` extension, but there doesn't seem to be a way to [view the debug log/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243350/how-to-view-log-output-when-developing-in-visual-studio-codes-remote-container)
- Finding a parameter to add to the `docker-compose up ...` that would map the ports when I run them, but there doesn't seem to be [an option for this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

Comment: You should be able to use both `ports:` and `expose:` together.  For that matter, you should be able to communicate between containers without `expose:` too.  Does using [an extension YAML file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to supply the port definitions for development mode do what you want?

Comment: they aren't clashing with each other, but if I use `ports:` then travisCI will fail, but I need `ports:` to develop lcoally.  Seems like my question is bad and not related to `expose:` at all